# How to add new row at the bottom of the table in angular ng2 smart table

Tags: angular

I am using angular ng 2 smart table to display the table content. The table data is displayed as expected. But when i want to add new row, it is getting added at the top of the table. can anyone help me to add the row at the bottom of the table.

Comment: for what angular version?  You can use sort by id for it.

Comment: I am using latest angular cli. could you please send me the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet in your add row method

```
addData() {
  let temp = _.cloneDeep(this.data);
  temp.push({
    id: 11,
    name: "ashraful islam",
    username: "ashraful",
    email: "ashraful@test.biz"
  })
  this.data = [];
  this.data = temp;
}
```